# Will "Apply update from SD card" delete my data?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, sd-card, data, rom-update

Will I lose my data when using Recovery's `Apply update from SD card` option? And, if so, will I lose data on the phone, on the memory card or everywhere else?

---

Phone: Samsung SM-A107F/DS (Galaxy A10s)
System: Android 11, One UI Core 3.1
Bootloader version: U8
Recovery: stock
Root: **NO**

Comment: there is no factory reset on *Apply update from SD card*, 90% sure you won't lose data. however, some weird situation may occur where update is too new and encryption has changed to unsupported conversion (must not happen, but random people claimed)

Comment: And in rare cases after applying an update the device is no longer able to fully boot (e.g. boot-loop). In such a case your data is still present but the only way to "recover" the device is by performing a factory reset.